# Cannot get karma test to pass on controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to create a "To Do list" in angular js. Upon completing a task, I want to be able to click on a checkbox to mark for completion.  Although it is working on the index.html, I cannot get the test itself to pass.

This is my test:

```
describe('ToDoListController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('ToDoList'));

  var ctrl;

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    ctrl = $controller('ToDoListController');
  }));

  it('initialises with an empty list and term', function() {
    expect(ctrl.listDisplay).toEqual([]);
    expect(ctrl.taskTerm).toBeUndefined();
  });

  describe('when viewing the to do list', function(){

    it('displays list items', function() {
      ctrl.taskTerm = "hello";
      ctrl.addTask();
      expect(ctrl.listDisplay[0].task).toBe("hello");
    });

    it('is completed when clicked', function() {
      ctrl.taskTerm = "hello";
      ctrl.addTask();
      ctrl.isCompleted("hello");
      expect(ctrl.listDisplay[0].completed).toBe(true)
    });

  });
});
```

and this is my controller:

```
toDoList.controller('ToDoListController', [function() {

  var self = this;
  self.listDisplay = []

  self.addTask = function() {
    self.listDisplay.push({task: self.taskTerm, completed: false})
  };

  self.isCompleted = function(item) {
    var i = self.listDisplay.indexOf(item)
    self.listDisplay[i].completed = true
  }
}]);
```

the error I'm getting back is:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'completed' of undefined
    at self.isCompleted (/Users/edobrien/Documents/Projects/todo_challenge/js/toDoListController.js:13:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/edobrien/Documents/Projects/todo_challenge/test/toDoListController.spec.js:26:12)
```

For reference, the error is occuring at the "ctrl.isCompleted("hello");" line

Any help you guys can give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller's `isCompleted` method is wrong: your list is an array of objects, no strings:

```
self.addTask = function() {
    self.listDisplay.push({task: self.taskTerm, completed: false})
};
```

If you set taskTerm as "hello", the object that is pushed into the array is not the string "hello", but an object like

```
{task: "hello", completed: false}
```

So when you try to find it with indexOf("hello"), it will always return -1, because

`"hello" != {task: "hello", completed: false}`

Change the way you look up an object in your array:

```
self.isCompleted = function(item) {
    var completed=false;
    self.listDisplay.forEach(function (value,index) {
        if (value.task ==item) {
            completed=value.completed;
        }
    });
    return completed;
};
```

**UPDATE**: I made a mistake when reading your code: `isCompleted` is the usual name for a method that **checks** if something... well, if something is completed. But actually your method **sets** it as completed. That kind of methods are usually named `setCompleted`.

So the method should be something like this:

```
self.setCompleted = function(item) {
    self.listDisplay.forEach(function (obj,index) {
        if (obj.task ==item) {
            obj.completed=true; //setting it as completed
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm now getting  TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: There is a typo, I wrote ListDisplay instead of lisDisplay... updating it... and you shouldn't just C&P the code! ;P

Comment: haha sorry, I was jsut seeing if it worked! ListDisplay is the correct array, i'm confused what you're askign to correct

Comment: The attribute starts with lowercase, but I put an upperCase "L": self.ListDisplay

Comment: ok,  it's now no longer returning as undefined but the completed value is not changing in the test! Thank for all your help mate, only been doing js for like 2-3 weeks and still confused by some things

Comment: I've updated the answer... I think now I got it right ;)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all your help! Also cheers for the update on the info about js conventions!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76872/discussion-between-munded-and-pablo).